# Mark a single member as private

Tags: c++, private, public

In C++, I am working with a macro where I need to define two variables, the first of which should have the same public / private / protected status as the scope where it is defined, while the other should plainly be private. However, if I just do:

```
#define my_macro(a, b) int a;\
private: int b;
```

then I have permanently changed the scope! This is not good. So I am wondering: is there any way to say: "only *this* variable / member / method / class is private"?

I naively tried doing something like

```
class my_class
{
   public:

   int i;
   private int j;
};
```

But no luck. Is there any way to get what I need?

**EDIT**: I am not sure that the scope in which the macro is defined is public. As I said, "*[...] the first of which should have the same public / private / protected status as the scope where it is defined*", so either public or private or protected, depending on the scope.

Comment: you can declare anything after private to be public again the same way.

Comment: you can take the scope of a as a parameter of your macro and reinstate it at the end

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's the point of such a macro? What it seems to achieve right of the bat is make it harder for other developers to read the code of your classes for little to no obvious benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there isn't. There are a few workarounds though:

1. Restrict your variables to a base class from which you inherit, and use your macros there. (Use `protected` rather than `private`).
2. Use an inner `struct` adopting similar techniques to (1).
3. Do the pragmatic thing and have the macro set either the first or final block of members.
4. Don't use macros at all as, generally, they are a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you assume that the 'default' scope is public, you could always change your macro to:

```
#define my_macro(a, b) int a;\
private: int b;              \
public:
```

Or even:

```
#define my_macro(a, b)       \
private: int b;              \
public:  int a;
```

Or if you're not sure what the default scope is, you can always add it as a macro parameter:

```
#define my_macro(scope, a, b) int a;\
private: int b;                     \
scope:
```

Comment: there is nothing in the OP question that imply so, actually OP is saying: "the first of which should have the same public / private / protected status as the scope where it is defined"

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt feature in language to do that. There are no `push` and `pop` settings kind of thing as with `warning` and other aspects for pre-processor on some compilers.

The bigger question is *Why*? You declare class' skeleton and change it rarely later. It's not worth the effort. Also, it will make code less readable and complex to maintain.

Don't waste your time on it. I won't be productive or useful.